# Gradle test task does not run JUnit test with @Category and @RunWith annotations

Tags: java, gradle, junit

Gradle does not run my JUnit test with @Category and @RunWith annotations.

Java 8, Gradle 4.2.1.

My JUnit class:

```
public interface FastTest {
}

@Category(FastTest.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        // Test method should fail
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile "junit:junit:4.12"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-core:1.6.5"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:1.6.5"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.5"
    compile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.5"
}

test {
    scanForTestClasses = false

    useJUnit { includeCategories 'FastTest'  }
}
```

If I remove RunWith annotation, Gradle runs the test. 
The scanForTestClasses = false setting has no effect.

Comment: No. It has to be Gradle.

Comment: It looks like PowerMock replaces @Category annotation with a proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377634/runwithpowermockrunner-class-does-not-work-with-package-annotation?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Reported Gradle issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3189.

PowerMock replaces Category annotation with a proxy: [RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) does not work with package annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377634/)

Workaround: Add PowerMockIgnore annotation to JUnit class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.junit.experimental.categories.Category", "mypackage.FastTest" })
@Category(FastTest.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        // Test method should fail
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just ran into this same issue. It's worth noting that "FastTest" also needs to be the fully qualified package/class name just like "Category" is fully qualified.